# How to detect if a node is removed from the DOM and return the index position

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I learnt that you check for elements removed from the DOM by binding the target element to the `DOMNodeRemoved` event. Later on I found this has been deprecated and has been replaced with `mutationObserver()` method. I have been reading about this API but it seems there is no way I can return the *index position* of the element that was removed from the DOM.

Can someone please help me return the position of the element with `class="post-container"` ?

JS:

```
// select the target node
var target =document.getElementById('post-line');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

    if (mutation.removedNodes) {
        //if the element removed has class='post-container' , then get the index position
        console.log( mutation.removedNodes.index() );
    }
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true,subtree:true ,removedNodes: NodeList[1]};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="post-line">

    <div class="post-container">
        <div><span></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-container">
        <div><span></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-container">
        <div><span></span></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found for tracking many changes occurring at once is reconstructing the original children arrays for each modified target by enumerating the mutations in reverse order and then getting the indices from these reconstructed arrays. This also solves the problem that a mutation's reported `previousSibling` and `nextSibling` may have been modified by another simultaneous mutation contained in `mutations`.

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    // oldParents and oldChildren keep track of the modified targets
    var oldParents = [], oldChildren = [];
    // make a copy of all the modified targets' childNodes
    for (var mutation of mutations) {
        var target = mutation.target;
        if (oldParents.indexOf(target) === -1) {
            oldParents.push(target);
            oldChildren.push(Array.from(target.childNodes));
        }
    }
    // enumerate all mutations in reverse order
    for (var mutation of mutations.slice().reverse()) {
        // (optional) find the first modified ancestor
        var target = mutation.target, ancestor = target, indexPath = [], found;
        do {
            found = false;
            for (var i in oldChildren) {
                var index = oldChildren[i].indexOf(ancestor);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    indexPath.push(index);
                    ancestor = oldParents[i];
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        } while (found);
        // remove added children
        var children = oldChildren[oldParents.indexOf(target)];
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
            // the index of the first added node, the other ones are consecutive
            var index = children.indexOf(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
            children.splice(index, mutation.addedNodes.length);
        }
        // add removed children back
        if (mutation.removedNodes.length > 0) {
            // the index of the first removed node, the other ones are consecutive
            var index;
            if (mutation.nextSibling) {
                index = children.indexOf(mutation.nextSibling);
            } else if (mutation.previousSibling) {
                index = children.indexOf(mutation.previousSibling) + 1;
            } else {
                index = 0;
            }
            children.splice(index, 0, ...mutation.removedNodes);
        }
    }
});
```